# Issue while redirecting, it is going to related list but not detail

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, ui

Issue while redirecting, it is going to related list but not detail.

**Component**

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                navEvt.setParams({
                    "recordId": component.get("v.createdOpp"),
                    "slideDevName": "detail"
                 });
            navEvt.fire();
```

Comment: Your problem looks strange and funny, the code which you have mentioned above navigates properly to the record detail page.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm).
It specifies that **"This attribute has no effect in Lightning Experience."**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is case sensitive. You've specified `Detail`, it should be `detail`. And also for **slideDevName** `detail` is the default value.

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
    "recordId": component.get("v.createdOpp"),
    "slideDevName": "detail"
 });
navEvt.fire();
```

Refer this [e.force:navigateToSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm)

Comment: Still it is not working.

Comment: @EffatNaaz Are you getting recordId. Put an alert above setParams and see if you're getting a recordId

Comment: yes i am getting record id also